# Windows Home Server

Tags: windows, home-server

I have a shrink wrapped copy of Windows Home Server that I received for a usability study I participated in.

So I know what the software does, but what *else* can I do?

I assume it installs like normal Windows, can I then RDC in if I need to?

Can I mount it as a drive on Mac Clients (like my laptop)?

Can I run a small home website besides the stuff it does? Like Maybe apache on 8080?

I wonder if a PII with 2GB would be enough for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can RDP to it

You can mount its drives from your Macs by going to Connect to Server and entering smb://servername

You can stream media from your WHS to other Windows computers/Xboxes in your home

[This](http://www.homeserverhacks.com/search/label/software) website has a lot of how tos and 'hacks'. There is a lot of bundled software floating around on the Internet that will let you expand your WHS' capabilities.

As far as the P2 with 2GB of disk space..I'm going to say 'no' to that. I think Win98 is the last OS that could run decently on that machine.

Comment: @josh - no 2gb RAM, not HD. There is 250gb hd space.

Comment: You might be able to coax it to run-but its not going to be pretty. If this answered some of your questions, you should vote for my comment.

Comment: @josh- OK, thanks, I have a much better extra box for sure.

Comment: "Decently" is of course subjective. I had XP running usably on a PII.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Home Server is built on Server 2003, so you can do alot of what you can do with Server 2003, you can RDP to it, you can mount network shares etc. It also comes with the added facilities of being able to back up your whole network, stream media, manage users and a wide variety of plugins to do other things.

As it is basically Server 2003, your going to need a reasonable spec PC to run it (although nothing amazing), it needs at least 5Gb of space just to install windows, then you will need alot of space for your backups.

Comment: You can run it on a very low-end computer. I used a Dell D600 as my WHS for a couple years. I had two 160GB drives in it (one in the HD slot, and one in the DVD/expansion slot). That was enough until I wanted to store videos.  Laptops make awesome servers.